# generate encrypted signature with private key

Tags: node.js

Good afternoon I would like to generate an encrypted signature of a string with my private key (pem) in nodejs but it marks the following: TypeError: Passphrase required for encrypted key

```
firma = `||${transferecias.institucionContraparte}|${transferecias.Empresa}||`;
     console.log(firma);

     var absolutePath = path.resolve('ruta\certs\\prueba-key.pem');
     var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
     var buffer = new Buffer(firma);
     var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);

     console.log(encrypted);
```

Comment: Please write in English on StackOverflow.

Comment: looks like path is not resolving properly. Can you make sure you have something in variable absolutePath.